# Reading objects SharedPreferences android json

Tags: android, json, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have a small problem while reading objects via SharedPreferences.
When I write something it successfully writes it but when I try to retrieve it , it gives a Json Syntax Exception. I am passing / retrieving an ArrayList.My object classes are implementing Serializable. Error :

IllegalStageException expected a String but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Here's my code :

```
public static boolean saveObject(String objKey, Serializable dataObj, Context con) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(dataObj);
    editor.putString(objKey, json);
    return editor.commit();
}

public static Object getObject(String objKey, Context con) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(objKey, "");
    Object o = gson.fromJson(json, objKey.getClass());
    return o;
}
```

How do I do the methods :

```
        if(ReadWrite.isCustomStringExistInLocal("levels", this)){
        System.out.println("Exists");
        levels = (ArrayList<Level>) ReadWrite.getObject("levels", getApplicationContext());

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("New");
        levels = new ArrayList<Level>();
        int teller =0;
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            levels.add(new Level(0, 0, teller));
            teller+=6;
        }

        ReadWrite.saveObject("levels", levels, this);

    }
```